# how to pass query params as array in API calls

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to call an API call that accepts array

```
params = {
  uid,
  pid,
  favorites: [102,110,112,125]
};

const options = {
  uri: host + url,
  method,
  headers,
  qs: queryParams,
  body: payload,
  json: true,
};


try {
  const reply = await request(options);
  // console.log('server__reply>>>', reply);
  return reply;
} catch (err) {
  logger.error(`Error::  "${err.message}"`);
  // logFailed(service, host + url, reply.status_code, reply.text);
  throw new BadRequestException();
}
```

but whenever i execute the code the params are passed as `favorites[]=102,110,112,125`

but not as `favorites=[102,110,112,125]`

is it possible to pass the array, since i can't alter the API since its a third party API

Comment: What does the third party API's documentation say about the format of how you should send the `favorites`? Maybe is should be stringified? `favorites: JSON.stringify([])`

Comment: @zishone when using stringify "["102","110","112","125"]" it takes whole array as string not array

Comment: have you tried using axios?

Comment: yeah i have tried with axios same result, its problem with API also requested the issue. currently used `.toString()` and just passed single variable